# How do I load a SQL lite db into a ListView in Eclipse, or should I not use List View?

Tags: android, android-listview

I am trying to load this into a list view? I was thinking that it may by OnLoadComplete....but I can't figure out how to declare the SQL lite into a variable that I can utilize in the List View

public class DisplayActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display);

     Button edit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnEdit);
     edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), EditActivity.class);
                v.getContext().startActivity(myIntent);
            }

        });

    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);


    /**
     * CRUD Operations
     * */
    // Inserting Contacts
    Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");
    db.addContact(new Contact("Ravi", "910-000-0000"));
    db.addContact(new Contact("Srinivas", "919-999-9999"));
    db.addContact(new Contact("Tommy", "952-222-2222"));
    db.addContact(new Contact("Karthik", "953-333-3333"));

    // Reading all contacts
    Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all contacts..");
    List<Contact> contacts = db.getAllContacts();       

    for (Contact cn : contacts) {
        String log = "Id: "+cn.getID()+" ,Name: " + cn.getName() + " ,Phone: " + cn.getPhoneNumber();
            // Writing Contacts to log
    Log.d("Name: ", log);

    ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewdb);
    list.toString();
    }
```

}
}

Comment: Is this Eclipse or Android?

Comment: For Android, using Eclipse